# Add new document into an array if there is no same field value in any other array embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I have a document

```
{
   _id:1,
   persons:[
     {name:"Jack", age:10},
     {name:"Ma",age:20}

   ]

}
```

I want to push new document `{name:"Ho",age;22}` in `persons` array. But there is a condition-
the new document will be added to array if name `name:"Ho"` does not exist in other embedded array documents. If exists, `{name:"Ho",age;22}` will not be added to `persons` array.
What is the way?

Comment: I think you can use a `$ne` condition in the update's condition, specified on the field `persons.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator along with [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to query the document that doesn't a person with that name.

Your update would look like this

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1,
  persons: {
    $not: { $elemMatch: { name: "Ho" } }
  }
}, { $push: { persons: { name: "Ho", age: 30 } } })
```

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the correct _id ? Make sure the query works by passing the query to .find()

Comment: I have updated the code, forgot to put the `persons` key

Comment: Your solution works, I'll upvote. But this solution should also work, check [playground](https://play.db-ai.co/m/Xu4YBwbYvgABFWeT)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
db.collection('test').update({
  _id: 1,
  "persons.name" : {$ne:"Ho"}
}, { $push: {persons: { name: "Ho", age: 30 } }  })
```

Comment: I checked  it again, it works, it is suggested by @prasad_